# Define show instance for ADT

Tags: purescript

I tried to define a show instance for an ADT, but I get the error `Argument list lengths differ in declaration show`. How can I make this work without using `Generic`?

```
data Route = Home | Users String | User Int | NotFound String

instance showRoute :: Show Route where
    show Home = "Home"
    show Users str = "Users"
    show User i = "User"
    show NotFound str = "404"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap constructors with arguments in parenthesis. Try something like this:

```hs
instance showRoute :: Show Route where
  show Home = "Home"
  show (Users str) = "Users"
  show (User i) = "User"
  show (NotFound str) = "404"
```

`Show` RELATED SIDE NOTE:

You can also derive `Show` instance for such a simple type using `purescript-generic-reps`, but you have to derive instance for `Generic` first:

```hs
import Data.Generic.Rep (class Generic)
import Data.Show.Generic (genericShow)

data Route = Home | Users String | User Int | NotFound String
derive instance genericRoute :: Generic Route _

instance showRoute :: Show Route where
  show = genericShow
```

I've made simple snippet so you can play with it on [try.purescript.org](http://try.purescript.org/?gist=2dbdf649d3d4e39ccc2859bd935b9139)

It's even possible to mix these two approaches:

```
instance showRoute :: Show Route where
  show (Users u) = "CusomUsersShow " <> u
  show u = genericShow u
```

For debugging purposes you can always use `traceAny` (`traceAnyA`, `spy`, etc.) from `purescript-debug`. Personally I'm writing `Show` instances only when I have to (forced for example by `purescript-test-unit`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this thorough reply!